# if the row has specific value, delete row from MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to delete Rows if two of columns from row has maximum value in its column. Or it has MIN column and MAX column at the same time.

```
BEGIN
DELETE FROM scores WHERE (second, third) 
IN ((MAX(second),MAX(third)));
select * from scores;
END
```

I have three columns first, second, and third. What I tried to do from above query, I tried to delete row if second and third has maximum value from its column. It gave me an error.

```
ERROR 1111 (HY000) at line 70: Invalid use of group function
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write two conditions separately, try this:

```
DELETE s.* FROM scores s
WHERE second = (SELECT second FROM (SELECT MAX(second) AS second FROM scores) a)
AND third = (SELECT third FROM (SELECT MAX(third) AS third FROM scores) b);
```

Comment: It gave me an error below. ERROR 1093 (HY000) at line 71: You can't specify target table 'scores' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Updated the answer, try now?